# How to make an object follow a track in 3D graphics

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, 3d

I managed to get my object to move along the track, and when it is travelling from left to right it also faces in the direction of travel, but on the back half of the track where the object is travelling right to left it flips upside down and I can't figure out why.

You can see this in action by cloning [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Bikeman868/frag) and just opening the `./samples/truck-on-track.html` file in your browser. There is no need to install anything or run anything, this is a static html page.

The important parts of the code are:

```js
const track = [
       0,  -50,    0,
      40,  -65,   10,
      90,  -35,   60,
      10,  -15,  250,
     -60,  -40,  130,
    -120,  -35,   30,
     -20,  -57,    5
];

const actions = [];
const invLinearVelocity = 3;
const invAngularVelocity = 30;
const position = truck.getPosition();
const truckPosition = [0, 15, 0];
for (let iThis = 0; iThis < track.length; iThis += 3) {
    const iNext = iThis + 3 >= track.length ? 0 : iThis + 3;

    const thisTrackLocation = Vector.extract3D(track, iThis);
    const nextTracklocation = Vector.extract3D(track, iNext);

    const vector = Vector.sub(nextTracklocation, thisTrackLocation);
    const angleY = Math.atan2(vector[2], vector[0]);
    const angleZ = Math.atan2(vector[1], vector[0]);
    const nextAngle = [0, angleY, angleZ];

    actions.push(frag.PositionAnimationAction(position)
        .rotateTo(nextAngle, invAngularVelocity));
  
    actions.push(frag.PositionAnimationAction(position)
        .moveTo(Vector.add(nextTracklocation, truckPosition), invLinearVelocity));
}
frag.Animation().sequence(actions, true).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My math was just flawed. After some research I wrote this function, which solved the problem. Take a look at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Bikeman868/frag) for a complete solution. The key function is:

```js
eulerAngles: function(directionVector, upVector) {
    const Vector = window.frag.Vector;
    if (!upVector) upVector = [0, 1, 0];

    const dir = Vector.normalize(directionVector);
    const up = Vector.normalize(upVector);

    const pitch = Math.asin(dir[1]);
    const yaw = Math.atan2(dir[0], dir[2]);

    const wingDir = [-dir[2], 0, dir[0]];
    const vertical = Vector.cross(wingDir, dir);
    const roll = Math.atan2(Vector.dot(wingDir, up), Vector.dot(vertical, up));

    return [roll, yaw, pitch];
}
```